# hist2d stripes when saving as pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf

I am plotting a 2d histogram with matplotlib. When I save it as a pdf file, stripes can be seen (not when I see it directly on the spyder IDE, for example).

I am opening it with okular and atril and the problem is there in both cases. You can find the picture attached (the green lines are part of the plot. But the white stripes should not be there).

The stripes are not there if I save the file as png, for example.

Any ideas or suggestions?

[image]

Comment: The stripes are there because matplotlib actually saves the figure data as very small rectangles. Due to the interpolation algorithm of your PDF viewer, it does not exactly align the rectangles correctly (even though they should be; if you zoom in very far, you should see that the edges match up). You might be able to fix it by adding the argument `rasterized=True` to your `hist2d` call, but then you also might lose detail in your image depending on the dpi of your figure (as the histogram is converted to a bitmap image and inserted in the PDF).

Comment: I used ax.set_rasterization_zorder(2), which I guess it is equivalent

Comment: The y-axis labels are also affected by this. Blurred, somehow. Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: Saving the pdf with a bette quality did the trick: in my case, dpi=200

Comment: Note that `set_rasterization_zorder(2)` also rasterizes the axis lines, ticks, and labels, as you suggested, because these are then also rasterized. Specifically setting `rasterized=True` on the `hist2d` call only rasterizes the actual 'image' data, and keeps the axis borders, ticks, and labels as vector graphics.

Comment: Thank you! Good point!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what other people have suggested in the comments, you could also add to the call of the `hist2d` function the following piece:

```
edgecolor='face'
```

which changes the color of the border of every bin to match that of the bin's face.